# graphdb 7 free http authentication method

Tags: http-authentication, graphdb

which type of http authentication method is used by Graphdb Free 7? I've setup a user and enabled security via the GraphDB Free Workbench, and am trying to query my triple store using basic http authentication, but just getting 403: Forbidden responses.

Comment: Hi Steve, welcome to SO. Have you looked in the documentation? Over the Internet? Be aware that question here must show sufficient background research. here is http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.graphdb.net/Manual:

> User authentication is configured using the [Admin API](http://www.graphdb.net/Manual#admin) and from the login/client point of view this is a transparent setting; whether the store is set up for internal or external authentication does have any side-effect on the client API. If the authentication is external you do need a configuration file however, which is part of the standard setup of the [ASP.Net Membership](http://www.graphdb.net/Manual#https://www.google.be/search?q=asp.net+membership+provider) mechanism.